# Margin level formula breakdown

Tags: binance

I'm trying to make sense of the formula for margin level calculation as brought out [here](https://www.binance.vision/tutorials/binance-margin-trading-guide):

> Margin Level = Total Asset Value / (Total Borrowed + Total Accrued Interest)

For example, if my collateral is 1 BTC, ETH/BTC price is 0.1 and I borrowed 10 ETH, how would the following values be calculated?

- Total Asset Value
- Total Borrowed
- Total Accrued Interest

Is everything calculated in terms of base (ETH) or quote (BTC) asset?

---

Based on my intuition, I could come up with the following breakdown, but would like a confirmation.

For example, if `hour = 1` (time of borrow) and `eth_hourly_interest_rate = 0.001`:

- Total Asset Value = `collateral + (borrowed * current_price)` = 1 BTC + (10 ETH * 0.1) = 2 BTC
- Total Borrowed = `borrowed * price_at_borrow` = 10 ETH * 0.1 = 1 BTC
- Total Accrued Interest = `hour * eth_hourly_interest_rate * current_price` = 1 * 0.001 ETH * 0.1 = 0.0001 BTC

Therefore, margin level = 2 / (1 + 0.0001) = ~1.998

In this example, both `current_price` and `price_at_borrow` are the same for simplicity, but `current_price` would change in time while `price_at_borrow` will stay the same.

Answer (score 3):

Total Accrued Interest for n hours = eth_hourly_interest_rate_hour(0,1) * eth_hourly_interest_rate_hour(1,n) * Total Borrowed * current price